# Callback after animation ends doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I want to make animated SVG restart on click, but only after it finished its animation.

My current code is as follows:

js:

```
$('.svg-icon').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('completed');
    $('.path-01, .path-02, .path-03').fadeOut(0, function() { $(this).fadeIn(); })
});

$('.path-01').one('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd', function() { $('.svg-icon').addClass('completed'); });
```

scss:

```
svg {
    max-width: 400px;
    display: block;
}

.path-01, .path-02, .path-03 {
    stroke-width: -1px;
    stroke-dasharray: 100;
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
}

.animate {
    @include animation(stroke-animation 5s ease-in forwards);
}

@include keyframes(stroke-animation) {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

You can see it at codepen: http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/XmrjRR

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the callback that doesn't work but it's the `addClass` function that doesn't work with SVG. Use `attr` instead and you will see in the inspector that the class is being added:

```
$('.path-01').one('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd', function() { 
    $('.svg-icon').attr('class', 'svg-icon completed'); 
});
```

Another problem is that `$('.completed').on('click', ...)` registers the event handler only for elements that are present at the moment when it's being invoked and there is none so it will be never called. You'd have to do it when the animation is completed.

Here is a [fixed codepen](http://codepen.io/LukaszWiktor/pen/ZbzBYa).

Comment: Thanks, Łukasz. I used `attr('class', 'svg-icon completed')`, because your solution didn't work. Also, with `click` I used `$(document).on('click', '.completed', function() {`, as you can see in the fiddle.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski sure, I forgot about 'class'! I will update my answer.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski and `$(document).on('click', '.completed', ...)` is even simpler solution than registering the callback after each animation end (as in my codepen).